# Batch conversion of xlsx to xls via CLI?

Tags: file-conversion, ms-office, python, open-source

I'm trying to convert a bunch of xlsx files to xls (because some other software`<cough>`matlab`<cough>` can process xls but not xlsx on the mac).

I've tried [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) but it has issues (which apparently stem from pyuno's shared object not being 64-bit-compatible -- even trying to override this with

```
$ VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes ./unoconv
```

still dies, this time with `Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)` which I'm surmising has to do with a mismatch between the python used with OpenOffice and the one shipped with MacOS X).

I'm using the Microsoft-provided "Open XML Converter" in the meantime, but I'd really like to figure out a way to do it with FOSS tools and via the shell.  Any ideas?

Oh, I'm running on Snow Leopard if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this with .xls(x) files per say, but I have used LibreOffice to batch convert .doc(x) files to .pdf using the `convert-to` option.  OpenOffice has the same options, afaik.

Check the `help` option for your app.  In my case it was:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice -help
```

In particular, for my switch to .pdf files, I did something like this:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice -headless -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.doc
```

The `-headless` flag just prevents the whole GUI from loading.  There is likely a similar output file extension and filter (the `pdf:writer_pdf_Export`) for your .xls(x) case.

Comment: OK, thanks-- OpenOffice 3.3 doesn't have seem to have the -convert-to (and -headless claims to be recognized, but still causes the GUI to fire up).  LibreOffice does the trick (though it still seems to be spending time firing up a bunch of stuff in the background).  I used this command line: `$ /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to xls 'test 1873.xlsx'`

Comment: The LibreOffice icon will show up in the dock, but I don't' get it loading a bunch of stuff.  Also, for my install, the options aren't long options - they only have one `-` character, not two.  That is interesting about OpenOffice not having these options.  There is probably a way to define a macro in OO and then call that macro from the command line, but I'm unsure.

Comment: I get it loading stuff (lots of disk spinning and time elapsed) and actually switching visual focus to the space (virtual desktop) where I have OO pinned -- not intolerable, but not what I would have hoped for "headless".  Oh, this is on LibreOffice 3.4.5 OOO340m1(Build:502)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm using LibreOffice 3.3  330m19(Build:401).  Not sure what has changed, but at least it is working for you now :).